# How to Invoke a method that take a Callable Interface or method as parameter with java reflection

Tags: java, lambda, reflection

Assume that I hava a Method that take Callable interface as parameters.

With java reflection.I want to invoke a method that take a `method` as parameter.

I got an Exception:`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

Below shows my code.

Any one knows how to archive my intent?

Appreciate for you answer!

```
package com.helloworld;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

/**
 * @author linjiejun 
 */
public class FinallyBlock {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//        template(FinallyBlock::tryThrowFinallyReturn);
//        template(FinallyBlock::tryReturnFinallyReturn);
//        template(FinallyBlock::tryCatchFinallyAllReturn);
//        template(FinallyBlock::gotoFinallyIfMeetReturnInTry);
//        template(FinallyBlock::gotoFinallyIfMeetReturnInCatch);
        
        Method[] methods = FinallyBlock.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        Method templateMethod = FinallyBlock.class.getDeclaredMethod("template", Callable.class);
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals("main") || method.getName().equals("template")) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(templateMethod.invoke(null,method));
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private static <T> T template(Callable<T> callable) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-----begin-----");
        System.out.println(callable.call());
        System.out.println("*****end*****");

        return null;
    }

//    private static int tryThrowEx() {
//
//    }

    //region finally 中有return 语句，try,catch block中的return，以及抛出异常都将失效。
    //
    // try 中抛出的异常，对catch依旧有效。
    private static int tryThrowFinallyReturn() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    private static int tryReturnFinallyReturn() {
        try {
            return 1;
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    private static int tryCatchFinallyAllReturn() {
        try {
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 2;
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    //endregion

    /**
     * try 中没有遇到return语句的内容会执行
     * try 中遇到return语句，
     * 就将控制权转移给
     * finally block
     *
     * @return
     */
    private static int gotoFinallyIfMeetReturnInTry() {
        try {
            System.out.println("try_before_return");
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    /**
     * catch block 同 try block
     * catch block 中没有遇到return语句的内容会执行
     * 遇到return语句
     * 就将控制权转移给
     * finally block
     *
     * @return
     */
    private static int gotoFinallyIfMeetReturnInCatch() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("catch_before_return");
            return 2;
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    private static int tryReturnFinallyNot() {
        try {
            return 1;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally block");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `templateMethod.invoke(null,() -> method.invoke(null))` or just `templateMethod(() -> method.invoke(null))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `template()` method accepts a `Callable<T>`, instead you pass it a `Method` which does not implement `Callable<T>`, thats why the error. You need to implement the Callable Interface.

So, just as suggestion you could do something like this

1- create a Callable Class (you can do an anonomus class if you want)

```
public class MyCallableMethod implements Callable<Integer> {

    private Method m;

    public MyCallableMethod(Method m){
       this.m=m;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return this.m.invoke(null);
    }
}
```

2 change

```
System.out.println(templateMethod.invoke(null,method));
```

whith

```
System.out.println(templateMethod.invoke(null,new MyCallableMethod(method)));
```

Of course this is just a trace of work with "theoric" code, as i cant neither write, neither compile nor debug the code.

Another solution could be change the signature of template() from

```
 private static <T> T template(Callable<T> callable)
```

to

```
private static <T> T template(Method callable)
```

and  change the method body accordingly, but i believe you need callable for some type of concurrent task